# jQuery - Show entered text from input field as heading for Dynamically added block

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

jQuery with Bootstrap Modal...

I am creating info boxes dynamically and allowing users to type box heading through input textbox and clearing the input after adding it...

First time, it is working as expected.. where as If I try to create one more box, previously created boxes headers also changing... :(

How can I create a box with unique textfield every time?

> **[Online Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ReddyPrasad/3yz9te79/)**

**HTML**

```
<div class="container wrapper">

  <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i> Add More
  </button>

  <div class="box-holder clearfix">

  </div>

</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form role="form">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="title">Title:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="options">Options:</label>
            <select id="mySelectOptions">
              <option>Option 1</option>
              <option>Option 2</option>
              <option>Option 3</option>
              <option>Option 4</option>
              <option>Option 5</option>
              <option>Option 6</option>
            </select>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="addBox" data-dismiss="modal">Add Box</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('#addBox').click(function () {
    $( ".wrapper .box-holder" ).append( '<div class="new-box"><div><label class="box-title">Title: <span></span></label></div><div><label class="box-values">Values: <span></span></label></div></div>' );

   var newTitle = $(".modal-body .form-group #title").val();
   $(".new-box .box-title span").text(newTitle);

    $(".modal-body .form-group #title").val('');

  });       

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's simply because when you do this:

```
$(".new-box .box-title span").text(newTitle);
```

You target every html item that correspond to this selector. And this selector is the same for every box so you just change them all. A good strategy could be this:

```
$('.new-box:last-of-type .box-title span').text(newTitle);
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1ogee98n/

For more information about the `:last-of-type` selector, you can check out the jQuery official's documentation right there: https://api.jquery.com/last-of-type-selector/

Comment: Thanks **@Yann Chabot**

Comment: It's my pleasure @Reddy , does that answers your question properly?

Comment: **@Yann Chabot** Yes.. ofcourse.. I have Accepted your answer as well :)

Comment: I was going to suggest using a new function, but your idea is brilliant, very nice Yann ;)

Comment: @JonathanXXI Thanks alot :-)